# Docker-compose with setup.sql file for H2 docker database

Tags: sql, docker, docker-compose, h2

I have a problem with creating docker container with h2 database. I would prefer making it through docker-compose file with setup file setup.sql mounted in local host directory. Any ideas if it is even possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
./your-scripts-sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```